# How to convert datetime into string and declare as parameter in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have date time field in my table.  i want to convert into string and declare as parameter.

For example when datetime field is not null then 'OPEN' and datetime field is null then 'CLOSED' and when i enter the parameter, i want type 'OPEN' or 'CLOSED' then the result will display the text in the table.

How to do that?.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite follow your question about using the 'parameter' but hopefully this will give you most of what you need.

```
SELECT CASE 
           WHEN [Date_Column] IS NULL THEN 'CLOSED'
           ELSE 'OPEN'
       END
FROM [Your_Table]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I understand your question: you want a query with a string parameter accepting two fixed values, either `'OPEN'` or `'CLOSED'`, and you want one to match non-NULL values of a certain `datetime` column in your table, and the other to match NULL values of the same column. And you also want to display values of that column as `'OPEN'` or `'CLOSED'` accordingly.

If that is correct, you could try the following:

```
DECLARE @QueryParam varchar(20);
SET @QueryParam = 'OPEN';

SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT
    OpenOrClosed = CASE WHEN DateTimeColumn IS NULL THEN 'CLOSED' ELSE 'OPEN' END,
    other columns as necessary
  FROM yourtable
) s
WHERE OpenOrClosed = @QueryParam;
```

You might also want to consider rewriting the subselect as a view:

```
CREATE VIEW YourTableView
AS
SELECT
  OpenOrClosed = CASE WHEN DateTimeColumn IS NULL THEN 'CLOSED' ELSE 'OPEN' END,
  other columns as necessary
FROM yourtable
```

Then you would just select from that view:

```
DECLARE @QueryParam varchar(20);
SET @QueryParam = 'OPEN';

SELECT *
FROM YourTableView
WHERE OpenOrClosed = @QueryParam;
```